# Mercurial changing file names to Upper Case and doesn't track them

Tags: mercurial, commit, addition, fogbugz, kiln

I've been having some problems with mercurial and kiln, maybe you can point me in the right direction. Sometimes when I commit the files they get renamed as Upper Case 'Assembly.NameSpace' will be changed to 'ASSEMBLY.NAMESPACE' and if I try to commit after making changes to them they appear as not being tracked (Side note I found out about the renamed files after I committed).

No matter what I do they just wont be tracked. I tried add using the console, using hg workbench and nothing seems to work. For it to work I need to forget the files, then commit, then add them again and then commit, which it really sucks for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to latest version will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible the files already exist in the repository with different case?  "Case Folding" is a problem for any system that needs to work on both systems that are truly case sensitive and those that are only case retentive.  Mercurial has done a lot of work to degrade as well as possible when a case folding problem arises and there's a lot of detail about it in the Mercurial wiki.

On what OS are you working?

When you do that initial add of the files are you using a wildcard or specifying them by name?

Do the files on disk actually change case when you add them?  Mercurial only alters files in the working director (the stuff outside of `.hg`) on `update`, so it seem pretty much impossible that just doing `hg add; hg commit` would change the case of a file in the working directory.

Comment: Hi, It seems it's a known bug. Reference https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1521/file-not-tracked-error

Comment: Looks like the solution is to just upgrade, it is fixed in the latest TortoiseHg version.